# Touch command "Invalid timestamp" android phone

Tags: terminal, android, touch, phone

I have used the adb shell command to shell into my android device.

I then tried to run the command...

```
touch -t 201108231405.14 *.png
```

To changed the modified time of all the files in the Photos directory of the device.

The error message I get is....

```
touch: invalid timestamp specified
```

What is wrong with the timestamp I am providing?

Trying the following command doesn't work and spits out the output...

```
touch: usage: touch [-alm] [-t YYYYMMDD[.hhmmss]] <file>
```

EDIT:

I have also tried this format and it didn't work...

```
1|shell@jfltecan:/sdcard/Pictures/ $ touch -t -c 20110823.140514 *png       
touch: invalid timestamp specified
```

I have also tried the following command which also did not modify the timestamp...

```
shell@jfltecan:/sdcard/Pictures/NYC $ touch -a -t 20110823.140514 *.png
touch: usage: touch [-alm] [-t YYYYMMDD[.hhmmss]] <file>
ouch -a -t 20110823.140514 IMG_2880.png                                       <
255|shell@jfltecan:/sdcard/Pictures/NYC $ ls -l IMG_2880.png
-rwxrwx--- root     sdcard_r 12462866 2017-09-04 14:39 IMG_2880.png
shell@jfltecan:/sdcard/Pictures/NYC $
```

Answer (score 0):

As you see here `touch -t` creates the files before modifying the file.

```
touch -a    To change file access and modification time.
touch -m    It is used to only modify time of a file.
touch -r    To update time of one file with reference to the other file.
touch -t    To create a file by specifying the time.
touch -c    It does't create an empty file.
```

Another way would be :

```
touch -d '23 August 2011 14:05:14' *.png

-d, --date=STRING
              parse STRING and use it instead of current time
```

Comment: see edit to question.